# Tree and Graph on same set of vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Suppose you are given an undirected graph G and a tree T on the same set of vertices.
We would like to know whether it is possible to have an adjacency list representation
of G (note that there are multiple options here as the adjacency list can arrange the
neighbours of a vertex in any order) such that running Breadth First Search on G with
this adjacency list will result in T being the BFS Tree. Give an efficient algorithm to
solve this problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If T is rooted, then all we have to do is initialize Bellman--Ford with the distances implicitly given by T, perform one relaxation round, and return true if and only if nothing changed.

If T is not rooted, then I guess we can try all possible roots, but it does feel as though there should be a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: Tree is rooted and there exist a linear-time algorithm. But I don't about it.